# PHP:Merge array values when key has same value

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional Array like this. Which I have to sort in some way where the same user's data will be stored in one array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => example@gmail.com
            [available_date] => 2018/06/30
            [available_time] => 06.00,06.30,07.00,07.30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => example@gmail.com
            [available_date] => 2018/06/31
            [available_time] => 06.30,07.00,07.30,08.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => newuser@gmail.com
            [available_date] => 2018/06/31
            [available_time] => 08.00,08.30,09.00,09.30
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => newuser@gmail.com
            [available_date] => 2018/06/30
            [available_time] => 08.30,09.00,09.30,10.00
        )

)
)
```

I want the final array to be like this,Where available_date and available time will be merged as an array with a key name for a same user.Maybe this is easy but I am stuck.Any help would be appreciated.

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => example@gmail.com
            [date_time] => Array
            (
              [0]=>Array
                (
                  [date] => 2018/06/30
                  [time] => 06.00,06.30,07.00,07.30,
                )
              [1]=>Array
                (
                  [date] => 2018/06/31
                  [time] => 06.30,07.00,07.30,08.00,
                )
             )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => newuser@gmail.com
            [date_time] => Array
            (
              [0]=>Array
                (
                  [date] => 2018/06/31,
                  [time] => 08.00,08.30,09.00,09.30,
                )
              [1]=>Array
                (
                  [date] => 2018/06/30,
                  [time] => 08.30,09.00,09.30,10.00,
                )
             )
        )

)
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried something like this.  $response=array();$user_email=$result['user_email'];  foreach ($result as $value) {         $data=array('available_date'=>$value['available_date'],'available_time'=>$value['available_time']);
 array_push($response, $data);
 }$res['user_email']=$user_email;
  $res['available_list']=$response;
  print_r($res); It's just listing all the date time inside first user array. Let me check if I can solve the problem using @Alessandro's solution

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
$x =
[
    "0" => [
            "user_email" => "example@gmail.com",
            "available_date" => "2018/06/30",
            "available_time" => "06.00,06.30,07.00,07.30",
        ],

    "1" => [
            "user_email" => "example@gmail.com",
            "available_date" => "2018/06/31",
            "available_time" => "06.30,07.00,07.30,08.00,"
        ],

    "3" => [
            "user_email" => "newuser@gmail.com",
            "available_date" => "2018/06/31",
            "available_time" => "08.00,08.30,09.00,09.30",
        ],

    "4" => [
            "user_email" => "newuser@gmail.com",
            "available_date" => "2018/06/30",
            "available_time" => "08.30,09.00,09.30,10.00",
        ]
];


$result = [];

foreach ($x as $item) {
    $temp['date'] = $item['available_date'];
    $temp['time'] = $item['available_time'];
    $result[$item['user_email']]['date_time'][] = $temp;
}

print_r($result);
```

And the result is this :

```
Array ( [example@gmail.com] => Array ( [date_time] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => 2018/06/30 [time] => 06.00,06.30,07.00,07.30 ) [1] => Array ( [date] => 2018/06/31 [time] => 06.30,07.00,07.30,08.00, ) ) ) [newuser@gmail.com] => Array ( [date_time] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => 2018/06/31 [time] => 08.00,08.30,09.00,09.30 ) [1] => Array ( [date] => 2018/06/30 [time] => 08.30,09.00,09.30,10.00 ) ) ) )
```